# ggplot - extrafonts: can't add specific Marvel-themed font

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I have seen similar questions around the web, but none of the solutions I have tried seem to work for this specific font.
I have downloaded the "Hall of Heroes" font here: https://www.dafont.com/hall-of-heroes.font
but it's impossible for me to load it in R.
I have tried the function `font_add` but get the following error:

```
Error in check_font_path(regular, "regular") : 
  argument "regular" is missing, with no default
```

Similarly, with `font_import (#path)` I get the following error:

```
Scanning ttf files in C:/Users/maria/Desktop/StartUp ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
C:\Users\maria\Desktop\StartUp\hall_of_heroes\hallheroes.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
Found FontName for 0 fonts.
Scanning afm files in C:/Users/maria/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/extrafontdb/metrics
Warning message:
In system2(ttf2pt1, c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  :
  running command '"C:/Users/maria/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rttf2pt1/exec/ttf2pt1.exe" -a -G fAe "C:\Users\maria\Desktop\StartUp\hall_of_heroes\hallheroes.ttf" "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpG2ofYs/fonts/hallheroes"' had status 5
```

the problem seems to be specific to this font, any ideas? does it work for anyone else?